# How to Shortcircuit a Laravel Query

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Within an Eloquent model, I have a scope which I want to return records if the current user has a certain role and nothing if he does not.

I am looking for a way to 'shortcircuit' the query and return an empty array. For now, I have used the following but I feel there must be a better way:

```
public function scopeForClient($query, User $user)
{
    if ($user->hasRole('client')) {
        return $query->whereIn('client_id', $user->id);
    } else {
        return $query->where('id', false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would leave only this part in your scope `return $query->whereIn('client_id', $user->id);`

```
//User model
someFilterFunction($query){
  if ($user->hasRole('client'))
      return $query->forClient();

return [];
}

//Other parts of your application
$result = someFilterFunction($query);
if (!empty($result)) {
    // do something with query Builder instance
}
```

I would avoid doing additional query to database here `$query->where('id', false)` when there is no need and you know it will return empty result;